# Python: How to use collections? [problem]

Tags: python, python-3.x

****Problem Statement:****

Commonwealth games are here, and Peter Quill, the head of the fixtures department is a big problem. Given a list of countries which are going to participate in the games, he has to create two pools for the games, with each country in either of the two pools. However, due to increasing cases of corruption and collusion between countries in games, there is a new rule this time. No two countries sharing a geographical border will be kept in the same pool, to maintain fair play and diversity. Can you help Peter decide whether two pools can be created as per the rules or not, for a given set of countries?

**Input format:**

The first line contains two space separated integers n (number of countries) and m (number of pair of countries sharing a geographical border).  Next m lines contain two space separated integers from 1 to n representing two countries which share their geographical borders.

**Output format:**
If two pools can be created, 'yes', otherwise 'no'

**Example:**

**Input:**

```
5 5 
1 2 
1 3 
2 4 
3 4 
4 5
```

**Output:**

```
yes
```

**Explanation:**

From the given inputs, it is clear that

1 has 2,3 as neighbors.

2 has 1,4 as neighbors.

3 has 1,4 as neighbors.

4 has 2,3,5 as neighbors.

5 has 4 as a neighbor.

By little observation, it is clear that two pools can be formed i.e `(1,4)` and `(2,3,5)`.

---

I've tried from this problem to get the inputs the `n` and `m`, and the other lines inside a list, each one as a indepedent list. This is the result so far but i dont know how to do the comparison between the lists and neighbors.

I just need the idea of reasoning, not the code solved.

```
n, m = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
countries=[]
neighbors=[]
for i in range (m):
    countries.append([int(x) for x in input().split()])
print (countries)

>>[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Comment: I'd build the pools up gradually.  Start with one country and all of its neighbors; put that one country in one pool, and all the neighbors in another.  Go through the bigger pool and validate that none of the countries in that pool are neighbors of one another.  Now go through all the other countries one at a time -- if they can be assigned to only one pool, assign; if no pools, return False; if both pools, skip for now and come back to it.

Comment: As you know that only two pools can exist, you can create two empty pools and then try to start adding countries from your list. Before adding, you check whether it can be added to the first pool (with your neighborhood constraints), else try to assign it to the second, but you also check this. If both are not possible, it fails. The checks can be done in a loop or with `all`/`any` and list comprehensions.

Comment: Please give your question a title that describes the specific problem, to aid people searching for similar questions in the future. All questions here are about solving problems, that's not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that your input is a text file, you can read it with:

```py
m = []
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    nm = list(map(int, file.readline().split()))
    for row in file:
        m.append([int(i) for i in row.split()])
```

In the easiest of the scenarios, if the number of countries is bigger than the number of countries with neighbors, then logically you can make two pools, since at least one of them will surely be able to fit a pool alone:

```py
if nm[0] > nm[1]:
    output = 'yes'
```

If it's not the case (it's not the case for your example), we'll need to manage `m`. Surely there're multiple ways to get this task done, but I'll go by creating a dictionary with country-neighbors as key-values, filling up the pools with target-countries if there're not neighbors in that list. If we can fill up all countries to either of the pool lists, output is 'yes', otherwise is 'no':

```py
# Get unique countries (we'll use them in the next line to identify all neighbors by country)
countries = set(sum(m, []))
# Get a dict with country and neighbors like in your provided explanation
country_neighbors = {c: [i if j==c else j for i,j in m if c in [i,j]] for c in countries}

# Create two empty lists
pool1,pool2 = [],[]
output = None

# Iterate through dictionary
for country,neighbors in country_neighbors.items():
    # Add country to first pool1 if there're not neighbors in the list
    if not any([neighbor in pool1 for neighbor in neighbors]):
        pool1.append(country)
    # If there's any country neighbors in pool1, try to place it in pool2
    elif not any([neighbor in pool2 for neighbor in neighbors]):
        pool2.append(country)
    # If no possible, then it's no possible to create two pools at all
    else:
        output = 'no'
        break

if output is None:
    output = 'yes'
```

---

If you want, you can wrap it inside a function like this:

```py
def check_pools(input_file):
    m = []
    with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
        nm = list(map(int, file.readline().split()))
        for row in file:
            m.append([int(i) for i in row.split()])
    if nm[0] > nm[1]:
        return 'yes'
    
    countries = set(sum(m, []))
    country_neighbors = {c: [i if j==c else j for i,j in m if c in [i,j]] for c in countries}
    
    pool1,pool2 = [],[]
    
    for country,neighbors in country_neighbors.items():
        if not any([neighbor in pool1 for neighbor in neighbors]):
            pool1.append(country)
        elif not any([neighbor in pool2 for neighbor in neighbors]):
            pool2.append(country)
        else:
            return 'no'
    return 'yes'
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot, i didn't expect this. That read from file is a plus, i was only putting the input manually, I never would have imagined making that dictionary matching both columns like you did in "country_neighbors", suppose i need to read more about python collections.